# how to easily develop print css?

Tags: css, printing

how to easily develop print css? with live preview/debugging, i'm on windows xp, use dreamweaver, and firefox is installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Temporarily set the stylesheet's `media` to `screen` instead of `print` and use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) and/or [Web Developer Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/60) with live CSS edit.

Comment: can we also do like this in dreamweaver?

Comment: Sorry, I don't do Dreamweaver, so I can't give a detailed answer about that. But if it supports live CSS edit as well, then you could still just temporarily change the `media` attribute to `screen`.